# R Shiny - Taking a snapshot of output to avoid recursion

Tags: r, recursion, shiny

Here is an example Shiny code I am running.
If the "Input Number" is 5. I want to set that to be the multiplier by clicking "Set as base". Then by ticking "rebase", and clicking "run", I want the output to be the input number * the multiplier.
So if I've set the base using the input number to be 5, then I want the output to be 5*the input for every input I give.
Then I might decide to make a new output the multiplier by clicking set as base.

Click order:

1. Run
2. Set As Base
3. Tick Rebase
4. Run

But I am getting this error:

evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

How do i get around this? I've tried the isolate expression without luck. Can't I just take a snapshot of the output when I click "set as base"?

```
tempserver<-shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
   
   res<-eventReactive(input$runit,{
      if(input$rebase){
        mult<-multipliyer()
        result <- input$numin * mult}
      else {result<-input$numin}
     result
    })
    

  output$resultoutput<- renderText({
    res()
    })
  
  multipliyer<-eventReactive(input$setbase,{
    mult<-res()
    mult
  })
  
})


tempui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(4,numericInput('numin', 'Input Number', 5)),
    column(4, actionButton("runit","Run")),
    column(4, actionButton("setbase","Set As Base")),
    column(4, checkboxInput("rebase","ReBase")),
    column(4, textOutput("resultoutput"))
    )
  
))

shinyApp(server=tempserver,ui=tempui)
```

Comment: `multipliyer` depends on `res` and `res` depends on `multipliyer`.  That's why you're getting infinite recursion.

Comment: Sure, but how can I just take a snapshot of res and assign it to multiplier when I click set as base?